# How to update variable and make it persistent in java?

Tags: java

For example, I have a private member initialized to String str = "A". After the program finishes, I want str to become "B". Then, next day when I run the same program, str's value is "B", not "A".

Thank you.

Comment: the next day ?! Sounds like you are telling a story.

Answer (score 5):

You need to write your data to a persistent storage location, such as a database or a file on disk.

Comment: Yes, I could write it to a file, but since it's a very small data. I am wondering if there is any way to avoid that.

Comment: @user697911 Either the program never stops executing (a bad idea - what if your computer crashes?) or it writes the data to a file or database. Your choice ;)

Comment: @user697911: You may want to use properties file.

Comment: Why a programing language doesn't support this feature? It seems to be a very useful one, and a simple thing to do.

Comment: Property file is still an physical file who values have to be read and write out?

Comment: @user697911: Programs execute in memory.  That memory is reclaimed by the operating system when the program exits.

Comment: It would be possible for a language or framework to automatically write to disk for you, but that would generally be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Would you please tell more  on "next day when I run the same program, str's value is "B", not "A". Where does urs program resides?Are u starting program again by starting a server ?
At last exit point of program call following code
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

```
public class Reflection {
    String str = "A";
    void test(){
        Class test=    Reflection.class;
        try {
      Field aa=      test.getDeclaredField("str");
      aa.setAccessible(true);
      try {

        aa.set(this, "B");
        System.out.println(str);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Reflection test=new Reflection();
    test.test();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Expanding on SLaks answer a bit) - if you want to persist any information in a program between executions, that information needs to be stored somewhere external to the program.  This can be a database (often for large/complex programs) or a file (for small programs), or anything in between (offsite cloud storage, etc).  The same concept is used in any desktop application that 'saves documents' - it's basically saved state in a file that you can reload through the program.

A simple example in Java is to use a properties file - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769063/java-write-properties-file) gives an example of how to write information to a properties file - you can use related API to read those properties back in when you start your application the next time.

If you're more adventurous, there are [several frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) in Java that provide persistence features, but this sounds like much more complexity than you're looking for in your app.